# ReactJs - trigger file download in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a link to a network file in my React app so that when clicked, the file downloads. Like this:

```
<a href="\\server\Test\test.xlsx">Direct link Test</a>
```

It works fine in a regular html page, but in Chrome, in a ReactJS app, I get the error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file://server/Test/test.xlsx

Any suggestions or workarounds for this? I've tried a variety of forward slashes, back slashes, window.open etc.

**Update:**
When I inspect the link in the browser, the path seems to be prepended with the site root url. So when I hover over the path in the code inspector, I see this:

> [http://some-intranet-site.com/\](http://some-intranet-site.com/%5C)\server\Test\test.xlsx

The "/\\" isn't a typo.

Comment: I think you need to provide absolute path of the file.

Comment: not the absolute *path*, the absolute *url*.

Comment: The file isn't on a webserver though, its in a local network storage drive

Comment: If the file isn't in the web server's accessible files you won't be able to do that. It'd be a huge security issue.

Comment: How come it can be done with IE then?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `target="_blank"` to your  tag

note: as someone else mentioned this is just a work arround. best way to resolve this making a http request to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

use the download attribute on the anchor tag.

```
<a href="\\server\Test\test.xlsx" download>Direct link Test</a>
```

keep in mind this is not a great way to do this. best practices for something like this would be to make an http call to an endpoint, or to use javascript's [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) method

Comment: Fetch and http call are not solutions to this problem, the files are stored in a network folder, which doesn't have a web service.

Comment: try using <a href="file:\\\server\Test\test.xlsx" /> you need to let the anchor tag know you're trying to serve up a local file via the file protocol. the href attribute must be the actual location on the server of the file. for instance to serve up a file located in my Program Files directory it'd have to be file:///C:/Program Files/myFile.xlsx. again, setting up an endpoint to serve these is a better solution. perhaps the above will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

First import the file and then try to handle download functionality. Check below code.

```
import template from '../server/Test/test.xlsx';
...
...
...
<input type="button" onClick={() => setTimeout(() => window.open(template), 100)} value="Download file" />
```

This will work for you!

Comment: First import the file and then try to download the imported file. It will work. I have updated my answer. Can you please check it.

Comment: The example I gave is over-simplified. There are many files paths, which are loaded from a db table so I cannot import them.

Comment: If you able to open file in new tab then try to set same path in `window.open('your-file-path')`. This will definitely work.